# localizer chinese word under placeholder not working

Tags: localization

This code is under .cshtml file, i try to use `@localizer` to translate the page to chinese and english. The localizer for english part work well which it can display the correct english word, But when i change to chinese word it display 
[image: localizer to chinese word]
Why is this happening? and how should i solve it?

```
$(".select-customer").select({
                    ajax: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomer","Order")',
                        width: 'resolve',
                        data: function (params) {
                            return {
                                q: params.term
                            };
                        },
                        processResults: function (data) {
                            return {
                                results: data.items
                            };
                        },
                        minimumInputLength: 2,
                        width: 'resolve'
                    },
                 placeholder: "@localizer["OrderSearchForCustomer"]", //localizer use over here
                 tags: true,
                 selectOnClose: true,    
                 
                 createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
                     if ($(data).filter(function () {
                         return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
                     }).length === 0) {
                         return { id: term, text: term };
                     }
                 },
             });
```